# How can I make sure the tab order for html elements will always behave the same regardless of page refresh or having navigated to the page?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, accessibility, tabindex, section508

The project I am working on is using AngularJS and uses UI-Router plugin to manage all the state/page changes.

When I go to certain page via clicking a button on the homepage of the of the app, the tab order of that page starts at the footer. However when I refresh that same page, the tab order correctly starts at the top of the page. I did notice that when I go to the page via the button from the homepage, and click on the top of the page before starting to tab, the tab order behaves correctly.

I did try adding tabIndex="0" to links in the primary navigation bar, however that didn't make any difference. Like I said, the page's tab order works perfectly fine when I refresh the page. It is only messed up when I navigate to the page from some other part of the site.

Is there a way to make sure that tab order will behave exactly the same no matter if I refresh the page, or whether I navigate to the page from another page of the site?

Comment: Do you have a sample URL? Any chance the button on the home page of the app is a link to an anchor (perhaps to `#footer` or similar)? Either way, `tabindex` will not do what I think you want to achieve; it simply makes an element focusable.

Comment: More context is needed.  Please post example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On statechange or when the controller is initialized and after the DOM has rendered, set the focus to the first control that fits your criteria.

Containing View:

```
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div id="tabContent" ui-view></div>
  </body>
```

Javascript:

```
var rootElementName='tabContent';
$timeout(function () {
                var formElements = $('#' + rootElementId)
                                     .find('select[disabled!="disabled"],input[disabled!="disabled"],textarea[disabled!="disabled"]');
                if(formElements && formElements.length > 0) {
                    formElements[0].focus();
                    return true;
                    } else {
                    return false;
                    }
            }, 0);
```

*You can do this in a service or directive. OR you can tie it to onEnter or the $viewContentLoaded event.

I included the id so you can target controls on a specific part of the page, and this example will focus the first select,input,or textarea control that is not disabled.